# Query not returning all results when joining

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on my PHP application, and got a problem with this query:

```
SELECT imagesets.id, imagesets.name, users.name AS username, users.email, COUNT(images.id) AS count
FROM fotosite.imagesets
INNER JOIN users ON imagesets.userid = users.id
INNER JOIN images ON imagesets.id = images.imageset
GROUP BY imagesets.id
ORDER BY imagesets.id desc;
```

However, that query doesn't return results where there are no data in the `images` table that matches the given ID.

For example, this query works fine, but does not give me the count column that I want:

```
SELECT imagesets.id, imagesets.name, users.name AS username, users.email
FROM fotosite.imagesets
INNER JOIN users ON imagesets.userid = users.id
GROUP BY imagesets.id
ORDER BY imagesets.id desc;
```

Comment: You're looking for a ``LEFT JOIN``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `INNER JOIN`. The INNER JOIN will only return rows where data is available in the second table for your join criteria. The LEFT JOIN returns also rows which can't be joined on rows in the other table.